# What is the etymology of どんちゃん騒ぎ?

Tags: words, etymology

WWWJDIC defines it as this:

> どんちゃん騒ぎ【さわ】 (n) merrymaking; high jinks; spree
>
> 観光客は町中飲み歩いてどんちゃん騒ぎをした。 The tourists painted the whole town red

What is the etymology of this word? Is it in common usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://gogen-allguide.com/to/donchansawagi.html

In summary, どんちゃん is the sound of drums and gongs accompanying a battle scene in Japanese classical drama.